# Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, nativescript-angular

The app i'm working on works in ios, but wont for android.
It has worked previously before updating the nativescript version to 3.4.3 from 3.4.1 and Mac OS to High Sierra.

I then had to update the Android Studio version.

The following is the output from tns debug android.

```
Searching for devices...
Preparing project...
Gradle build...
    + applying user-defined configuration from /Mobile/NativeScript-Projects/Genkan/app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle
    + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized
    + adding aar plugin dependency: /Mobile/NativeScript-Projects/Genkan/node_modules/nativescript-imagepicker/platforms/android/nativescript_imagepicker.aar
    + adding aar plugin dependency: /Mobile/NativeScript-Projects/Genkan/node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/platforms/android/TNSListView-release.aar
    + adding aar plugin dependency: /Mobile/NativeScript-Projects/Genkan/node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/platforms/android/TNSSideDrawer-release.aar
    + adding aar plugin dependency: /Mobile/NativeScript-Projects/Genkan/node_modules/nativescript-ui-core/platforms/android/TNSCore-release.aar
    + adding aar plugin dependency: /Mobile/NativeScript-Projects/Genkan/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/android/widgets-release.aar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Mobile/NativeScript-Projects/Genkan/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'outputFile' for task ':app:packageDebug' of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.

 * Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1.
```

the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.1">

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because of the incompatible java JDK version.
Please check your current java version using this command:
**java --version**

If there is java installed already then remove that version first, after that install LTS version of java jdk from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html

Answer (score 0):

From Docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_api

> However, more complicated tasks that involve accessing outputFile
>   objects no longer work. That's because variant-specific tasks are no
>   longer created during the configuration stage. This results in the
>   plugin not knowing all of its outputs up front, but it also means
>   faster configuration times.

Use `outputFileName` instead of `outputFile` in your `Gradle` configuration.

Comment: Does that mean i need to find that outputFile in one of the plugins?

Comment: This is what is in the app.gradle file

`android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "com.genkan.mobileapp" 
    
    //override supported platforms
    // ndk {
    //       abiFilters.clear()
    //     abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
   // }
  
  }  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
} 
`